# CloudFront ignores cache-control: no-cache response header

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, apollo-server

I'm running an Apollo GraphQL server behind a CloudFront distribution.

CloudFront TTL settings are set to the following:

- Minimum TTL: 0
- Maximum TTL: 604800
- Default TTL: 60

Testing locally, I'm able to see the `cache-control` header (no-cache). However behind the CloudFront distribution, `cache-control` header is missing:

**Local Test (no-cache)**
[image]

**CloudFront Test (no-cache)**
[image]

---

However, **when I set a cache-control max-age, it works both on my local machine & behind CloudFront**:

**Local Test (maxage 60)**
[image]

**Local Test (maxage 60)**
[image]

---

**Why does CloudFront ignore the cache-control: no-cache header? It seems that it defaults to my default TTL (60)**

Thanks and looking forward to any inputs!

Comment: CloudFront correctly handles (and passes through) `cache-control: no-cache` but your example of this not working is actually a cached response from CloudFront, so it's a little tricky to base any conclusions on that.

Comment: @naribo As Michael said in the comment, could you invalidate the CloudFront cache and try your first example again?